# ScrollViewClass must not be undefined - react native iOS

Tags: ios, react-native, scrollview, react-native-ios

I'm having an issue with ScrollViewClass being undefined but only in one location of the app and only for the iOS version in react-native.

ScrollView is used in multiple locations in the app and works fine but in this one particular part of the app, it results in an error screen stating that `ScrollViewClass must not be undefined`

[image: ScrollViewClass must not be undefined]

```
                    <ScrollView style={styles.descriptionContainer}
                            contentContainerStyle={styles.descriptionContainerInner}>
                    {/* The description text */}
                    <Text style={styles.descriptionText}>
                        {this.state.description}
                    </Text>
                </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 6):

... Basically, there was a bad equality checker of:

`if (Platform.OS = 'android') { ...`

for

```
componentDidMount() {  
    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
            BackAndroid.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackOnOverlay);
    }
```

Which resulted in the event listener being added for the android back button in the iOS app. The above errors were showing as a result of this it seems. Never assume the error message is the error as such.